# Image update and remove old image on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

Trying to implement update article in my update controller it seems works, but the problem is when I only want to update the post without uploading an image the old always getting remove which is it shouldn't.

here's my store function

```
public function store(Post $post)
{
        $post->update($this->validateRequest());
          
        $this->storeImage($post);
        

        return redirect('post/'.$post->id)->with('success', 'New ariticle has been posted');
    }

}
```

here's my validation

```
private function validateRequest()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'title'=> 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|max:5000',

        ]);
    }
```

here's my update function

```
public function update(Post $post)
{
        File::delete(public_path('storage/'.$post->image)); 
        $post->update($this->validateRequest());
          
        $this->storeImage($post);
        

        return redirect('post/'.$post->id)->with('success', 'This post has 
        been Edited');
    }

}
```

I've tried to add `File::delete` to my storeImage function and delete it from my update function, it fix the problem but the old image is not removed from directory

```
private function storeImage($post)
{
  
  if (request()->has('image')){
  File::delete(public_path('storage/'.$post->image))
  $post->update([
       'image' => request()->image->store('uploads', 'public'),
  ]);
  
  $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/'.$post->image))->fit(750, 300);
  $image->save();
        }
    }
```

Ok since I use model binding in my controller I don't have to find the id right?
so I change my update function which is basically Akhtar munir suggested, and turn out to be something like this. The image update work, it also remove the old image when I update it. But I have found another issue, the problem is when I edit article and title it didn't change like when I update it, I hope you can take look at this is this correct?

```
public function update(Post $post){
    $this->validateRequest();
    if(request()->hasFile('image') && request('image') != ''){
            $imagePath = public_path('storage/'.$post->image);
            if(File::exists($imagePath)){
                unlink($imagePath);
            }
            $image = request()->file('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
            $post->update([
                'title' => request()->title,
                'content' => request()->content,
                'image' => $image,
            ]);
        }
}
```

Comment: It works fine with `file::delete` the problem when I put it in update function is when I only want to update article without uploading new image, the image is getting removed because it always assuming there's an uploaded image.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which is the line in question?

Comment: I remove the `file:delete` in update function because it keep removing the old image even though I only update the article, so it should be a checker when a new image is uploaded the old image should be remove and new image replace the old one. I put `File::delete` in storeImage to check but somehow it keep passing the check.

Comment: Sounds good. What have you tried to implement that "checker"? Where are you stuck?

Comment: so I add this  `if` in my storeImage function like Rakibul's suggest but it didn't work, it did update the image but old image still stuck in store/uploads directory. PS. my english sucks plz dont bully me lol

Comment: Oh it work now, I forgot to add  update request after the whole `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have done in one of my method. It may help you.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if (UserDocument::where('id',$id)->exists()) {

        $this->validateUserDocument($request);
        
        if ($request->hasFile('doc_file') && $request->doc_file != '') {
            
            $doc = UserDocument::where('id',$id)->first();
            // dd($doc);
            $file_path = storage_path().'/app/'.$doc['doc_file'];
            //You can also check existance of the file in storage.
            if(Storage::exists($file_path)) {
               unlink($file_path); //delete from storage
               // Storage::delete($file_path); //Or you can do it as well
            }

            $file = $request->file('doc_file')->store('documents'); //new file path

            $doc->update([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'doc_file' => $file //new file path updated
            ]);

            session()->flash('success','Document updated successfully!');
            return redirect()->route('userdocs');
        }

        session()->flash('error','Empty file can not be updated!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    session()->flash('error','Record not found!');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

In this code, I just simply want to clearify to you that I have stored image path in database, first I have retrieved that path and with that path I have found image in my local storage, delete it first and then update it with the new one. But make sure to store image path in database in both cases ofcourse with insert and update.

So finally you can also optimize your code like this, it will do the same thing as you expect, whether image and all data or only title and content.

```
public function update(Post $post){
    $this->validateRequest();
    $data = [
        'title' => request()->title,
        'content' => request()->content
    ];
    if (request()->hasFile('image') && request('image') != '') {
        $imagePath = public_path('storage/'.$post->image);
        if(File::exists($imagePath)){
            unlink($imagePath);
        }
        $image = request()->file('image')->store('uploads', 'public');
        $data['image'] = $image;
        //$post->update($data);
    }
    $post->update($data);
}
```

Comment: I sorry for late reply, I make some change with code like you suggested, the image update it work and remove the old image when I update it, but another issue. please take a look, I edit my question and add the that you suggest I hope you can pointed if I do something wrong with my new code bellow.

Comment: You meant to say that you are currently now updating the image, but not article and title ?

Comment: And have you included `title` and `content` in your model `$fillable` property? if not, then include it and then see the result.

Comment: Okay dear, so again you have changed the question, let me tell you that when you are not uploading any image during update, then you have to first check if the is empty, if it is empty then you should only update title and content and you should not do the image stuff in this case and in else condition if it is not empty then you will update everything. I hope you understand.

Comment: I already add `$guarded` with empty array which is the samething. Yes I know the code supposed to if the `image` request is empty then it wil just update my `title` and my `content`, but if there's a file being upload in `image` request it will removed the file and replace with new one while updating `title` and `content` at the same time. but in my case the image work like it supposed to but content and title didn't get updated

Comment: and also see when you `dd(request->all());` your data during update, what data you get ?

Comment: `dd($request->all());` or `dd(request()->all());`

Comment: I add my model in question

Comment: where should I put this dd() should I put before `if`?

Comment: yes before if and validateRequest and check if your input names are correct, because sometimes debugging your code improve your mistakes, some silly mistakes and if insertion is okay then `$guarded` is okay for mass assignable.

Comment: And let me clearify one thing, `$guarded` is used for the inputs you don't want to insert or update etc while `$fillable` is used for mass assignable which means it should be inserted or updated when you are working with models.

Comment: it work I forgot to add the another update afte the whole if which is should update with only `content` and `title` if the whole condition is not filled. Thanks Akhtar Munir, now I can sleep peacefully.

Comment: yes, I already know abbout `$guarded` and `$fillable`. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah that's what I had told you before to update your record in both conditions, but I think at that time you didn't pick my point. Well you can sleep now, but it would be nice if you mark my answer as correct so that other can get help as well. Thanks and you welcome.

Comment: Also see my updated answer for your optimized code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
private function storeImage($post)
{

    if (request()->hasFile('image')){
        $image_path = "/storage/".'prev_img_name';  // prev image path
        if(File::exists($image_path)) {
            File::delete($image_path);
        }
        $post->update([
           'image' => request()->image->store('uploads', 'public'),
        ]);

        $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/'.$post->image))->fit(750, 300);
        $image->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work somehow it always keep passing the `File::exists` check

Comment: The name of file is taken from post function which is exactly the same with update function, I just add `File::delete` in storeImage function.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it